# code is giving syntax error and give KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python

A pet store keeps track of the purchases of customers over a four-hour period. The store manager classifies purchases as containing a dog product, a cat product, a fish product, or product for a different kind of pet. She found.
a. 83 purchased a dog product
b. 101 purchased a cat product
c. 22 purchased a fish product
d. 31 purchased a dog and a cat product
e. 8 purchased a dog and a fish product
f. 10 purchased a cat and a fish product
g. 6 purchased a dog, a cat and a fish product
h. 34 purchased a product for a pet other than a dog, cat or a fish.
i. How many purchases were for a dog product only?
ii. How many purchases were for cat product only?
iii. How many purchases for a dog or a fish product?
iv. How many purchases were there in total? `enter code here`

```
dcp=set(range(0, 83))
cpp=set(range(0, 101))
fpp=set(range(0, 30))
dfpp=set(range(0, 8))
dcpp=set(range(0, 31))
cfpp=set(range(0, 10))
dcfpp=set(range(0, 6))
opp=set(range(0, 34))
print("Purchsed for dog product only" , len(dcp) + (len(dcpp)) + len(dfpp) + len(dcfpp))
print("Purchased for cat product only" , len(cpp) + (len(cfpp)) + len(dfpp) + len(dcfpp))
print("Purchased for fish only" , len(fpp) - (len(cfpp)- len(dcfpp) + len(dfpp)))
print("Purchased for dog or a fish" , len(fpp) - (len(cpp)+ len(cfpp + 6))
print("Purchased total products" , len(dcp) + len(cpp) + len(fpp) + len(opp))
```

Comment: Count your (closing) parens. They don't match the opening ones, hence the sytnax error.

Comment: In the fourth print statement you have `len(cfpp + 6)`, I think you meant `len(cfpp) + 6`, and you're missing the closing parenthesis of the print statement.

Comment: Hi! Please read [ask]. If you're getting a syntax error, the traceback will report where that error occurs. It's good form to include this. I can already see that you have some mismatched parentheses.

Comment: You probably also want to just asign numbers (e.g., `dcp=83`) nd get rid of all the extra `len`s. Better variable names would make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed extra parentheses. If gives following:

```
dcp=set(range(0, 83))
cpp=set(range(0, 101))
fpp=set(range(0, 30))
dfpp=set(range(0, 8))
dcpp=set(range(0, 31))
cfpp=set(range(0, 10))
dcfpp=set(range(0, 6))
opp=set(range(0, 34))
print("Purchsed for dog product only" , len(dcp) + len(dcpp) + len(dfpp) + len(dcfpp))
print("Purchased for cat product only" , len(cpp) + len(cfpp) + len(dfpp) + len(dcfpp))
print("Purchased for fish only" , len(fpp) - len(cfpp)- len(dcfpp) + len(dfpp))
print("Purchased for dog or a fish" , len(fpp) - len(cpp)+ len(cfpp + 6))
print("Purchased total products" , len(dcp) + len(cpp) + len(fpp) + len(opp))
```

No error is with "cfpp + 6" what it should mean?

Comment: cfpp + 6 - cause error, yes. Question what it is supposed to be